# how Twilio Flex sending attribute to flex agent when a call comes from a specific number

Tags: flexbox, twilio

We're trying to find a way to advertise more numbers in different channels for our reservation and each channel have a number, so we know where the calls comes from to help the reservation team for better answering the calls

this attribute needs to be passed to the agent on Flex and for example show calls comes from Google , or facebook search or anywhere

how would we implemented it